# Realm wrong JSON parsing

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, realm

I'm parsing json via createObjectFromJson(Class, InputStream), then save it to database

All was perfect, until i changed

```
String name;
```

to

```
LocalizedString name;
```

and my json data

```java
  {
      "name": "Introduction",
```

to

```java
  {
     "name": {
       "en": "Introduction",
       "da": "Introduktion",
       "de": "Einführung",
       "ko": "소개"
     },
```

where LocalizedString now is

```
public class LocalizedString
          extends RealmObject {

   private String en;
   private String da;
   private String de;
   private String ko;

   //   +getters and setters

   }
```

Now all strings after parsing equals to null (i.e. en, da, de, ko)
**There is no errors shown during parsing**

**And the last strange thing: Color class parsed as well by the same way**

```java
  "color": {
  "red": 255,
  "green": 199,
  "blue": 60
}
```

and class:

```java
public class Color
        extends RealmObject{

    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;

    //+getters and setters
}
```

All json structure looks like this:

```java
{
  "name": {
    "en": "Active Aging",
    "da": "Aktiv aging",
    "de": "Aktiv im Alter",
    "ko": "액티브 에이징"
  },
  "programs": [
    //some other data
  ],
  "color": {
    "red": 255,
    "green": 199,
    "blue": 60
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: can you show us the code where you actually called the `createObjectFromJson`?

Comment: @DerekFung, there is no changes in code where i'm parsing json, only in model. Also it parsed succesfully all other parts of object, so I think it's senseless

Answer (score 0):

From what you provide, you used `createObjectFromJson(Class, InputStream)`, it means there is no `encoding` provided on how to read the the InputStream.

So I am suspecting the cause is due to encoding. You can verify that by changing all characters in the json as ASCII only, and see if it can parse successfully.

If this is the cause of the problem, you may need to read the InputStream as String with correct encoding (UTF-8?) and use `createObjectFromJson(Class, String)` instead.

Comment: I tried replace all values to english i.e. I created separated file where all values of en/da/de/ko was "test", but it didn't work                            
Same result, all strings are null

Comment: And even in that case probably the en value would be read succesfully, isn't it? But "en" values are null everywhere too

Comment: It is difficult to say, it depends on the implementation.